# Threads: how can you signal you're ready, if you're only ready when you're blocked?

Tags: c, multithreading

My situation is as follows: In C, I launch a `pthread` that eventually blocks waiting for input by calling a receive function. The data it expects to receive will be basically a response.

Back on my original thread of execution I want to wait until the launched thread is ready to handle the response before I do anything that might cause such a response to arrive. I don't want to cause a response to arrive before the launched thread is capable of receiving it.

Edit: the original thread sends a UDP packet. It doesn't know if the other end exists or not -- it's trying to learn about the other end. It draws its own conclusion depending on whether the launched thread receives a response by a certain timeout.

One problem I have is the launched thread is only truly ready when it's blocked. Any signal it gives before it calls the blocking receive function could end up being a "long" time before it's actually ready. How do you signal when you're ready, given that you're only ready when you're blocked?

Right now I `sleep()` after receiving the ready signal, which I know is no guarantee and has disadvantages.

Another question I have is can the signal be as simple as changing an int from `0` to `1` without any mutex protection? I read that [ints are not atomic](http://www.alexonlinux.com/do-you-need-mutex-to-protect-int). But I only want to know when an int stops being `0`, and this int is only ever going to change once from `0` to something other than `0`.

Comment: what kind of threading are you using? `pthread` ?

Comment: You don't synchronize threads with `sleep` but with condition variables. If you are using `pthreads`, take a look a [`pthread_cond_signal`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)

Comment: sounds like you need to rethink your architecture. A thread can only do one thing at once. You could signal right before you block, but that's not guaranteed. Your thread shouldn't block if it has work to do. There should be some kind of shared data queue where it blocks if it has nothing to do, or immediately gets to work if it does have something to do. As @Pablo said, conditional variables are the way to handle this.

Comment: @yano How would you change it? The main thread has plenty of work to do, but eventually he wants the answer to a particular question. To get that answer, he needs to send a message and a response will come. How do you make sure you're ready for that response before you send the message? My approach was to listen for that response on a separate thread, but the act of listening is blocking, hence the question.

Comment: @user3735178 Is the response coming over the network? On a socket?

Comment: Based on what you've said, I'm envisioning a scenario where you have a send thread and a receive thread, and you're sending a message that will elicit a response, but you don't want to send that message until you're SURE the listen thread is ready to receive a response? Yeah I'm not sure conditional variables will help you there. First solution that comes to my mind is some kind of state machine/handshaking. Your send thread can startup and send "Are you ready" periodically until it gets a response back, then you know your receive thread is ready and it can transition into an active state.

Comment: Why does it matter if the receiving thread is "ready"? If this is on a socket, a call to `recv(2)` in the receiving thread will just block until the main thread makes the request and the response returns. If all the receiving thread is doing is waiting for the response, why do you care if it blocks at `recv(2)` or before `recv(2)` waiting for the main thread to tell it it's ready?

Comment: Yes, this is over the network. I updated the OP. @bnaecker it's the other way around -- the main thread wants to know if the receiving thread has blocked on `recv(2)` before it sends its request. But how can you know that?

Comment: @user3735178 My point is that you don't *need* to know that. If there is a connected socket, data will be buffered by the OS until it is read. So if the main thread sends a response *before* the reader thread calls `recv(2)`, that call will return as soon as the data is on the socket (which may be immediately). If the main thread sends the request *after* the reader thread calls `recv(2)`, well, then the exact same thing happens: the reader thread will block until the data is ready. It makes no difference which happens first. The comments in Martin James's answer point this out in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer To The Actual Problem

Your real problem is entirely solved by the kernel's network buffering. Once you have a UDP socket created by `socket` and bound to a local port using `bind` then the kernel will hold incoming traffic to that port in a buffer until you call one of the `recv` functions.

So there is no need to carefully synchronize when `recv` is called.

## The Question As Asked

Things like Go / Golang and its asynchronous goroutines do blocking calls in a thread pool. So a goroutine does the blocking task, then switches to another goroutine on a different thread. It creates more threads to fully use all the CPUs when some are blocked.

If interested look at Go1.4 `src/runtime/proc.c` and `src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s`

In order to signal that your thread is in a blocking system call, you have to do an atomic write to a flag *just before* entering the system call. There is a very small chance of context switch between the flag write and the system call, which has to be handled for perfection, but this will be very unlikely.

And note, an atomic write. Not a semaphore or mutex, which are far more complex and likely to be interrupted.

Comment: @user3735178: Well yeah. Go's compiler was written in C until Go version 1.4 so it obviously works.

Comment: How does this answer the question of how to postpone sending the request until you're ready for the response?

Comment: On the blocking call thread just before calling the blocking system call, mark that you are ready using an atomic write. YES, there is a possible race condition. To be perfectly safe the code should handle it somehow perhaps with a timeout on the receive. But in practice the CPU will hardly ever drop a context switch in between the ready-write and the system call.

Comment: The point you're making about the kernel buffering after bind() is the actual answer I think, which you point out in "Update 2". If you want, you could make that more prominent. I'll mark it accepted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What @bnaecker says in comments, plus what sounds like confusing design.

If something needs to send a request and await a response, it's easiest if one 'tx/rx' thread does both.  So, can you queue a combo request/response struct, (well, pointer to one), to the tx/rx thread, (producer-consumer queue)?  It can then send the request, sequentially receive the response and fill in the response bit of the struct.  How you communicate the completed request/response struct back to its originator is up to you and your overall design. For a synchronous interface, you could send a semaphore or condvar in the request/response struct that the originator waits on - the tx/rx thread signals it when it has filled in the response, (or error message:).  For async, you could queue the r/r struct pointer back again on another producer-consumer queue.

For 'ultimate' flexibility, the r/r struct could contain a function pointer to a completion routine that the originator sets.  The tx/rx thread calls the completion routine with the r/r struct pointer as a parameter. The completion routine can then do whatever the originator desired - signal some condvar, queue off the struct, post the struct to some GUI input queue, whatever.

Comment: What if this happens: send a request, response arrives, sender calls recv(2) too late and misses the response.

Comment: @user3735178: Why do you think responses will just vanish? If you have a receiving socket open the kernel will buffer for you.

Comment: Isn't it true that the receiving socket isn't open and that buffering doesn't happen until `recv(2)` is called? The scenario I'm worried about is: send a request, response arrives and gets dropped, sender calls `recv(2)`.

Comment: @user3735178: Create a UDP socket. Call `bind` on it to give it a known port. It'll get buffered. Try it!

Comment: @user3735178: If you're on Linux or BSD do `man 7 udp` On Linux at least it contains information on how much memory you can expect the kernel to reserve for buffered UDP data. If you exceed that before you get the recv in, then you will lose data. But not before that.